# Can Not delete a file from directory using php

Tags: php

I have some files in the directory ../gallery/drawingimage/ i have to delete a file. I have written the following code. But it is not working.

```
<?php
include("../gallery/includes/connection.php");

$file = $_POST['fname'];

if($_POST['ptype']=='drawing'){
        $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM drawing WHERE pname = '$file'") or die(mysql_error());

         $data=$file.".jpg";
         $dir = "../gallery/drawingimage/".$data;
        // echo $dir;
         unlink('$dir');

    }


//  header("Location: ../cpanel.php");
```

Comment: off-topic: you are vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the single quotes - use

```
unlink($dir);
```

instead of

```
unlink('$dir');
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Zali's answer, php makes a distinction between single and double quotes, and no quotes at all.  Single quotes are not parsed for variables.  For example, the following:

$x = "Some Text"

print $x;

> > Some Text

print "$x";

> > Some Text

print '$x';

> > $x